# Edit a binary value in hexadecimal in chntpw?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to edit a Windows registry entry to change the key to my Bluetooth device to be able to dual-boot with my Bluetooth keyboard.

I know which registry entry to use and I can extract Windows' pairing key by running `hex KEYNAME` in the `chntpw` commandline. I open up `C:\Windows\System32\Config\SYSTEM` with `chntpw -e` and then can browse and print out the Bluetooth pairing key in hexadecimal.

Is there a command which will enable me to edit the Windows registry entry/key in hexadecimal and insert my Bluetooth key from Linux?

(See [the following Ubuntu forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1479056&p=9363229#post9363229) to see how to copy the key from Windows to Linux, but I'd like to do it the other way around, I have it paired in Linux and I'd like to copy the key to Windows.)

Comment: In order for me to show the pairing key from my Windows registry, I have to run `hex {KEYNAME}`. I'm assuming that it's just returning the value of the key in hexadecimal, which is more portable. However, I need to take the key in hexadecimal, convert it to binary, and edit the key in the registry editor. Is there a way to do that in `chntpw`? AFAIK `-d` just enters debug mode, what does that do?

Comment: That must be it. I'll try it out when I get back to a computer with a Windows registry.

Answer (score 0):

Type `?` in `chntpw` console, you will see that `ed` can edit a registry value.